# MySQL Generate conditional result based on join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables - department and employee.

Employee table: department_id is a foreign key from the department table (id column)

```
|-------------|------------------|---------------|-----------------|
|      id     | employee_no      | department_id |employee_manager |
|-------------|------------------|---------------|-----------------|
|       1     |      34          |    1          |  Robert         |
|       2     |      34          |    1          |  Timothy        |
|       3     |      35          |    1          |  John           |
|       4     |      36          |    2          |  Benjamin       |
|       5     |      36          |    2          |  Bryan          |
|-------------|------------------|---------------|-----------------|
```

Department table:

```
|-------------|------------------|---------------|
|      id     |  department_name | dept_location |
|-------------|------------------|---------------|
|       1     |   Billing        |    CA         |
|       2     |  Marketing       |    NV         |
|-------------|------------------|---------------|
```

I need help with a sql query that returns all rows in the employee table that matches the department_id in the department table with the following conditions.

1. If the department id matches more than one non-unique employee_no (for eg, department_id 1 matches employee_no 34 & 35), then the join should get the dept_location which is 'CA' from the department table.
2. If the department id matches unique employee_no even more than once (for eg, department_id 2 matches employee_no 36 twice), then the join from the department table is not applicable and the result should be 'NA'(Not Applicable) for the dept_location

My result should look like the table below:

```
|-------------|------------------|---------------------|-----------------|
|      id     | employee_no      | department_location |employee_manager |
|-------------|------------------|---------------------|-----------------|
|       1     |      34          |   CA                |  Robert         |
|       2     |      34          |   CA                |  Timothy        |
|       3     |      35          |   CA                |  John           |
|       4     |      36          |   NA                |  Benjamin       |
|       5     |      36          |   NA                |  Bryan          |
|-------------|------------------|---------------------|-----------------|
```

Comment: What if the department_id matches exactly one employee_no?

Comment: If the department_id matches only one employee_no, then we shouldn't join the dept_location and the result of the department_location should be 'NA' (Not Applicable). The join to the dept_location is only valid when there are 2 or more non-unique employee_no. I hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Then it sounds like condition 2 is irrelevant and basically we should just output the department location if there is more than one distinct employee in that department?

Comment: @Nick Yes, you got it. If there is only one distinct employee, then we hardcode the department location to 'NA' (not applicable in this case) without doing any join. Sorry I was not precise enough.

Comment: @Nick Your solution worked great for me. Thanks to you and others for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query that will work in versions of MySQL prior to 8.0. It uses a derived table of counts of distinct employees per department to determine whether to display the department location or `NA`:

```
SELECT e.id, e.employee_no, 
       CASE WHEN c.distinct > 1 THEN d.dept_location
       ELSE 'NA'
       END AS department_location,
       e.employee_manager
FROM employees e
JOIN (SELECT department_id, COUNT(DISTINCT employee_no) AS `distinct`
      FROM employees
      GROUP BY department_id) c ON c.department_id = e.department_id
JOIN department d ON d.id = e.department_id
```

Output:

```
id  employee_no employee_manager    department_location
1   34          Robert              CA
2   34          Timothy             CA
3   35          John                CA
4   36          Benjamin            NA
5   36          Bryan               NA
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2u8QTJteTuQNQnMczTojw1/0)

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if I understood, but it seems to me you can use a derived field, or at worst, an IF to choose between two different derivation formulas:

```
SELECT id, employee_no,       
    CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees AS e WHERE e.department_id = employees.department_id)           
    WHEN 2 THEN 'CA' ELSE 'NA'      
END AS department_location,     
employee_manager FROM employees;
```

## Test

```
CREATE TABLE department ( id integer, department_name varchar(30), dept_location varchar(30));
INSERT INTO department VALUES (1, 'Billing', 'CA'), (2, 'Marketing', 'NV');

CREATE TABLE employees (id integer, employee_no integer, department_id integer, employee_manager varchar(30));

INSERT INTO employees VALUES
(1, 34, 1, 'Robert'),
(2, 34, 1, 'Timothy'),
(3, 35, 1, 'John'),
(4, 36, 2, 'Benjamin'),
(5, 36, 2, 'Bryan');
```

Then the SELECT *appears* to be working:

```
SELECT id, employee_no,       CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees AS e WHERE e.department_id = employees.department_id)           WHEN 2 THEN 'NA' ELSE 'CA'      END AS department_location,     employee_manager FROM employees;
+------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+
| id   | employee_no | department_location | employee_manager |
+------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+
|    1 |          34 | CA                  | Robert           |
|    2 |          34 | CA                  | Timothy          |
|    3 |          35 | CA                  | John             |
|    4 |          36 | NA                  | Benjamin         |
|    5 |          36 | NA                  | Bryan            |
+------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that relies on window functions (available in MySQL 8.0), which avoids the need of a subquery.

The trick is to compare the minimum and maximum employee number for each department. If they differ, then we know for sure that more than one distinct employee belongs to the given department.

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.employee_no,
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(e.employee_no) OVER(PARTITION BY d.id) 
            = MIN(e.employee_no) OVER(PARTITION BY d.id)
        THEN 'NA'
        ELSE 'CA'
    END department_location,
    e.employee_manager
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN department d ON e.department_id = d.id
ORDER BY e.id
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bz7JfojNcFjkSr8hXYSmYD/1)** with your sample data returns:

```
| id  | employee_no | employee_manager | department_location |
| --- | ----------- | ---------------- | ------------------- |
| 1   | 34          | Robert           | CA                  |
| 2   | 34          | Timothy          | CA                  |
| 3   | 35          | John             | CA                  |
| 4   | 36          | Benjamin         | NA                  |
| 5   | 36          | Bryan            | NA                  |
```